# How would one specify a custom deleter for a shared_ptr constructed with an aliasing constructor?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

How would one specify a custom deleter for a shared_ptr constructed with an aliasing constructor?

```
struct Bar { 
    // some data that we want to point to
};

struct Foo {
    Bar bar;
};

shared_ptr<Foo> f = make_shared<Foo>(some, args, here);
shared_ptr<Bar> specific_data(f, &f->bar);

// ref count of the object pointed to by f is 2
f.reset();

// the Foo still exists (ref cnt == 1)
// so our Bar pointer is still valid, and we can use it for stuff
some_func_that_takes_bar(specific_data);
```

How will this line `shared_ptr<Bar> specific_data(f, &f->bar);` be modified to add a custom deleter?

Comment: You can't change the deleter on an existing shared object. Are you trying to get something else to happen in addition to destroying the `Foo`?

Comment: You mean that the deleter of specific_data is the same as the deleter of f?

Comment: Check out the example on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter

Comment: Both `shared_ptr` share ownership of the same underlying object. The deleter is a property of the shared object, not of the individual `shared_ptr` to that instance. You can't have two `shared_ptr` that share ownership of the same object but with different deleters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to add a custom deleter in the construction of the aliasing `shared_ptr`.

The deleter is associated with the managed object, not the specific `shared_ptr` instance that will actually call it. The deleter is stored together with the object in the shared control block.

So once all aliasing and non-aliasing `shared_ptr` instances to the shared object are destroyed, the last instance (whether it is aliasing or not) will call the deleter which was associated with the object when it was first put under `shared_ptr` control.

So to add a custom deleter for the `Foo` object, replace `std::make_shared`:

```
auto f = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(some, args, here), some_deleter_here);
```

`some_deleter_here` will then be called with the `Foo` pointer as argument, even if the aliasing `shared_ptr` is the last to be destroyed.

Note however that if you are using a custom deleter, then you probably are not creating the pointer with a simple call to `new`. The only correct way to delete an object created with `new` is to call `delete` on it, which is what the default deleter already does.